# python bokeh div method doesn't seem to wrap

Tags: python-3.x, bokeh

bokeh=='2.1.1', Python==3.8.3

I have a very large text, which i am fetching from callbacks, and i want div.text to get updated based on that. The text is comma separated strings. I had tried using sizing mode, but it doesn't seem to have an effect

```
div = Div(sizing_mode="stretch_height")
```

What effect was expected, if it was not auto wrapping functionality. Also, how do i achieve auto wrap functionality.

There is a thread where it says Div wraps text automatically, which is an effect i desire [github closed issue](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/8654). For my use case, i'd like it to exhibit the default please!

Answer (score 0):

The sizing mode does not have any effect on overflow wrapping. To do that, you will have to add the style manually. However, it seems you will also have to use a fixed width (and also specify that in the style as well). This is the only way I could get things working:

```
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.models import Div

div = Div(text="""

   << very long text here >>

""", style={"overflow-wrap": "break-word", "width": "600px"}, width=600)

show(div)
```